# Evaluating $\lim_{x\rightarrow\pi}\frac{\sin x}{x^2-\pi ^2}$ without L'Hopital

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I need to calculate the following limit (without using L'Hopital - I haven't gotten to derivatives yet):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\pi}\frac{\sin x}{x^2-\pi ^2}$$

We have $\sin$ function in the numerator so it looks like we should somehow make this similair to $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}$. When choosing $t=x^2-\pi ^2$ we get $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin \sqrt{t+\pi ^2}}{t}$ so it's almost there and from there I don't know what to do. How to proceed further? Or maybe I'm doing it the wrong way and it can't be done that way?

Comment: $x^2 - \pi^2 = (x+\pi)(x-\pi)$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Choosing the substitution $x - \pi = t$, with $t \to 0$, we have
$$\lim_{x \to \pi}\frac{\sin x}{x^2 - \pi^2} = \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\sin(t + \pi)}{t(t + 2\pi)} = \lim_{t \to 0}-\frac{\sin t}{t(t + 2\pi)} = -\frac1{2\pi}$$

Answer (score 5):

Do the substitution $\pi-x=t$, so your limit becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin(\pi-t)}{-t(2\pi-t)}=
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin t}{-t(2\pi-t)}
$$
which is elementary.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\frac{\sin(x)}{x^2 - \pi^2} = \frac{x}{x^2(1-\pi^2/x^2)} \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1 -\frac{x^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right) = \frac{1}{x} \frac{1-x^2/\pi^2}{1-\pi^2/x^2} \prod_{n=2}^{\infty} \left(1 -\frac{x^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)
\end{align}
Since no L'Hospital available, we consider of the sign of numerator and denominator as $x \to \pi^{+}$ and $x \to \pi^-$ to obtain
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to \pi}\frac{1-x^2/\pi^2}{1-\pi^2/x^2}  = -1
\end{align}
and hence
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to \pi }\frac{\sin(x)}{x^2 - \pi^2}
=
-\frac{1}{\pi} \prod_{n=2}^{\infty} \left(1 -\frac{1}{n^2}\right) 
= -\frac{1}{2\pi}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Consider we have $x^2-\pi^2=(x+\pi)(x-\pi)$ and we know that $\sin(x-\pi)=-\sin(x)$ yielding: $$ \frac{-\sin(x-\pi)}{x-\pi}\cdot\frac1{x+\pi}\to -\frac1{2\pi}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
=& \lim_{x \to \pi} \left[ \frac{\sin x - \sin \pi}{(x-\pi)(x+\pi)} \right] \\
=& \lim_{x \to \pi} \left[ \frac{\sin x - \sin \pi}{x-\pi} \times \frac{1}{x+\pi} \right] \\\end{align}$$

Note that the fraction on the left is almost the definition of the derivative for sine. 
Continuing,

$$\begin{align}
=&\ \cos (x = \pi) \times \lim_{x \to \pi} \left[ \frac{\cos x}{x+\pi} \right] \\
=& -\frac{1}{2\pi} \end{align}$$

Comment: You're using the derivative.

Comment: Other methods are using equal concept too. $lim_{x\to 0}\frac{sinx}{x}=1$ is not different from derivative for me. They are both connected to each other. Also, using Hopital is not so far from any of these two concept. There is no other method to be so far from Hopital!

Comment: From OP: “I haven't gotten to derivatives yet”.

Comment: @egreg Point taken. Though it's kind of weird introducing sine without derivatives.